# What assembler is appropriate for High-Fidelity PacBio reads

Tags: assembly, software-recommendation, long-reads, pacbio

What assembler is appropriate for High-Fidelity PacBio reads?

For example, canu is good for high-error PacBio reads. But what algorithm to use for HiFi reads? Would it be OK to use canu without the error-correction step?

Answer (score 3):

As recently [tweeted by A. Phillippy](https://twitter.com/aphillippy/status/1191821832891949056), Canu v1.9 now supports HiFi reads.

Therefore you should just read their manual and look for the implementation

:)

Answer (score 2):

From the group of Heng Li there is [hifiasm](https://github.com/chhylp123/hifiasm).

Answer (score 1):

The HiFi de novo assembly tool that **PacBio** has been developing is called **IPA**.

It’s available on [pbbioconda](https://github.com/PacificBiosciences/pbipa) for command line use, and as a push-button pipeline in their SMRT Link software.

I looked at a few examples of runtimes of **IPA** for different genome sizes:

3 Gb human genome – ~600 CPU hours
800 Mb complex plant – ~430 CPU hours
400 Mb plant - ~100 CPU hours

[Hifiasm](https://github.com/chhylp123/hifiasm) seems to be more efficient as far as I can tell. In [their paper](https://doi.org/10.1038/s41592-020-01056-5) they have a few nice tables comparing it to HiCanu, Peregrine and Falcon.

[image]